# Simplest way to represent an arbitrarily deep nested list in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, hierarchical-data, nested-lists

I'm new to Backbone.  I have an arbitrarily deep nested list where each node in the list could potentially have a child collection.  Eg:

```
item 1
  item a
    item i
    item ii
  item b
  item c
item 2
item 3
etc
```

I am wondering what is the simplest way to represent this data structure using Backbone.

If it matters, I do not have a preference between loading the entire structure initially, or  loading each level as it is needed.  Whatever is easiest.

I would prefer not to go the route of Backbone-Relational, as I have a feeling that is overkill for something like this.

Thanks (in advance) for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data structure looks something like this

```js
[
  {
    title: "item 1",
    nodes: [
      {title: "item a",
        nodes: [
          {title: "item i"},
          {title: "item ii"}
        ]
      },
      {title: "item b"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: "item 2"
  }
]
```

you could set up your hierarchy by overriding the parse method of your models:

```js
var Node = Backbone.Model.extend({
  parse: function(data) {
    this.nodes = new Nodes(data.nodes, {parse: true});
    return _.omit(data, 'nodes');
  }
});

var Nodes = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Node
});

var c = new Nodes(data_structure, {parse: true}); 
// parse: true is only needed if you pass the data as an argument
```

`Node.parse` extracts the `nodes` property from the data hash to build a custom attribute on the object and then returns the rest to let Backbone handle the other attributes. You then access the collection with `model.nodes`. And a Fiddle to play with http://jsfiddle.net/C8HGY/

Answer (score 0):

I would make a simple model, maybe with default attribute `children` set to `new Collection` (if needed). The main part is loading from JSON data to models.

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

});
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: MyModel,
    load: function(data) {
        for(var i in data) {
            if (_.isString(data[i])) {
                this.add(new MyModel({
                    title: data[i]
                }));
            } else {
                var collection = new MyCollection();
                collection.load(data[i]);
                this.add(new MyModel({
                    title: i,
                    children: collection
                }));
            }
        }
    }
});

var collection = new MyCollection();
collection.load({
    'item1': {
        'item a': ['item i', 'item ii'],
        0: 'item b',
        1: 'item c'
    },
    0: 'item2',
    1: 'item3'
});
console.log(collection);
```

Only that in this example items with "0" and "1" keys are going to the beggining of the collection, but you can see the idea.